# Component is being rendered but while testing it fails

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js, vue-test-utils

While debugging, component is being rendered(also in webpage) but while testing if the component exists or not, assertion is failing.
NOTE : Title and Top assertions are rendering thus assertion also pass but Tab assertion is failing

Test :

```
describe("Transaction", () => {
    let wrapper;
    let status = false;
    beforeEach(() => {
        wrapper = mount(TransactionList, {
            localVue,
            vuetify,
            i18n,
            store,
            router
        });
    });
    
    it("Title, Top and Tab components should render", () => {
        expect(wrapper.find({ name: "Title" }).exists()).toBe(true);
        expect(wrapper.find({ name: "Top" }).exists()).toBe(true);
        expect(wrapper.find({ name: "Tab" }).exists()).toBe(true);  // Assertion Failure
    });
```

Component :

```
<template>
       <Title/>
       <Top />
       <Tab />
   </template>
```

Comment: Found the solution so if anyone encountered,
 about find :  It basically checks the component's name against each child rendered, and then checks the constructor, and some other properties.
https://lmiller1990.github.io/vue-testing-handbook/finding-elements-and-components.html#finding-components-with-name-and-component

so Check the name and Component either wise we can also check via 
import the Component;
expect(wrapper.find(Componets).exists()).tobe(true);

Thanks